# How do I get the attribute of the nth child with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, element

I have my html code like:

```html
<ul id="abc">
<li><a href="http://koolfinance.blogspot.com/2011/06/laxmi-bank.html">Laxmi Bank</a></li>
<li><a href="http://koolfinance.blogspot.com/2011/06/nepal-development-bank.html">Nepal 

Development Bank</a></li>
<li><a href="http://koolfinance.blogspot.com/2011/06/clean-energy-development-

bank.html">Clean Energy Development Bank</a></li>
<li><a href="http://koolfinance.blogspot.com/2011/06/gorkha-development-bank.html">Gorkha 

Development Bank</a></li>
<li><a href="http://koolfinance.blogspot.com/2011/06/bank-of-kathmandu.html">Bank of 

Kathmandu</a></li>
<li><a href="http://koolfinance.blogspot.com/2011/06/nic-bank.html">NIC Bank</a></li>
<li><a href="http://koolfinance.blogspot.com/2011/06/bank-of-asia-nepal-limited.html">Bank 

of Asia Nepal Limited</a></li>
<li><a href="http://koolfinance.blogspot.com/2011/06/nepal-sbi-bank-ltd.html">Nepal SBI 

Bank Ltd.</a></li>

</ul>
```

I need to find the `href` value or a tag's target page of **specific index**. E.g.: if the index is 1, it should return: `http://koolfinance.blogspot.com/2011/06/nepal-development-bank.html`
I tried:

```js
$targetLink = $('#abc a:nth-child(' + myIndex + ')').attr('href');
```

but its returning **undefined.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting the wrong child element:

```
var targetLink = $('#abc li:nth-child(' + myIndex + ') a').attr('href');
```

Select the nth-child of the li and the child a of that.

here's a jsfiddle to demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/G5Cmn/

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of the zero-based index here. Take a look at my code sample to see the difference. Both options could work for you depending on what you want.

```
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#abc li:nth-child('+i+') a').attr('href'));
    alert($('#abc a').eq(i).attr('href'));

});
```

Comment: sorry to say that your fiddle won't work if we change i to 5 or value > 1

Comment: I apologize for the typo. Notice that `a` is always the FIRST child of its parent, `li`. `li` on the other hand is a child of `#abc`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you named your var `$myIndex` and that code references `myIndex`.  Variables in JS don't require a `$` prefix so it's not giving you error messages when you use `myIndex`. `myIndex` is `undefined` so your selector is evaluating to `'#abc a:nth-child(undefined)'` which is not a valid selector.

**edit**

[Here is some example code](http://jsfiddle.net/w7QVD/)

One other thing to note, in JS arrays are zero-based but the things in CSS like the `nth-child` selector are one-based so to get that second link you would need to set `$myIndex` to 2, not 1.

Comment: sorry to say that my variable myIndex has got exactly correct value i wanted... its not undefined